# How to make i3 contain "Always on top windows" in i3+KDE setup?

Tags: xorg, kde, window, i3-wm, plasma-5

#### The issue

The Plasma "Add Widget" window is always on top, and due to this i3wm is unable to tile it. Also, since it is outside i3's management, hence I can't focus on it as well, which prohibits me from providing any keyboard input to it.

> Using `xdootool` to focus the window works as indicated by successful keyboard input.

#### My attempt to a solution

I'm thinking that somehow disabling the "Always on top" state of the concerned window will allow i3wm to take over the window management and hence everything **should** start working as expected.

#### `xprop` of window

```
WM_STATE(WM_STATE):
        window state: Normal
        icon window: 0x0
_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 4178541
_KDE_SLIDE(_KDE_SLIDE) = 0xffffffff, 0x0
_KDE_NET_WM_SHADOW(CARDINAL) = 71303409, 71303410, 71303411, 71303412, 71303413, 71303414, 71303415, 71303416, 10, 10, 1, 1
_KDE_NET_WM_BLUR_BEHIND_REGION(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 326, 1, 0, 1, 327, 1, 0, 2, 328, 1050
_NET_WM_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 4294967295
_NET_WM_STATE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_PAGER, _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE, _NET_WM_STATE_STAYS_ON_TOP
_KDE_NET_WM_DESKTOP_FILE(UTF8_STRING) = "org.kde.plasmashell"
XdndAware(ATOM) = BITMAP
WM_NAME(STRING) = 
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "Plasma"
_MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 0x2, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK
_XEMBED_INFO(_XEMBED_INFO) = 0x0, 0x1
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x4400015
WM_HINTS(WM_HINTS):
        Client accepts input or input focus: True
        window id # of group leader: 0x4400015
WM_CLIENT_MACHINE(STRING) = "Utkarsh-PC"
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 14096
_NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST_COUNTER(CARDINAL) = 71303192
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "plasmashell", "plasmashell"
WM_PROTOCOLS(ATOM): protocols  WM_DELETE_WINDOW, WM_TAKE_FOCUS, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_SYNC_REQUEST
WM_NORMAL_HINTS(WM_SIZE_HINTS):
        user specified location: 0, 28
        user specified size: 328 by 1052
        window gravity: Static
```

Comment: You could try asking at our related site [unix.se], or at [Kubuntu Forums](https://www.kubuntuforums.net), [KDE Community Forums](https://forum.kde.org), and [reddit/kde](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/).

Comment: No, in fact, this is a bug I faced using there config.

Comment: I have, though, posted this question on reddit and unix SE also.